# difference between normal skewed distribution and skewed distribution

Tags: statistics, distribution

From what I've read normal skewed is a distribution that has all the properties of normal distribution and is skewed:

according to this resource:https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/skewed-distribution/#LogT

one criteria of normal distribution is location parameter(mean) defining peak. Which from my understanding means mode=mean.

So then only difference between normal skewed and skewed distributions are whether or not mode=mean?

Additional Question:
my distribution has mode=1, mean=1.6 thus it is right-skewed (not-normal) distribution. I've read that to fix skewness you can use either logarithms or quantile regression technique, in my case which technique is appropriate?